# When (and, if applicable, where) did ся cease to be a free clitic?

Tags: история-языка

Russian and other East Slavic languages are peculiar, by Slavic standards, in having a fixed post-verbal reflexive particle rather than a free one (or rather, one that tends to follow Wackernagel's law and come second in a clause).

It was already frozen in place by the time of the *Song of Igor's Campaign*, yet there are exceptions, such as this passage:

> Ту **ся** копиемъ приламати, ту **ся** саблямъ потручяти о шеломы половецкыя, на рѣцѣ на Каялѣ, у Дону Великаго.

So when did the change occur, and could it have been a regional phenomenon that went on to spread?

What's notable here is that, while unusual by Slavic standards, the affixed reflexive is consistently observed in North Germanic languages (Old Norse `-sk` yielding modern `-s`), while Polish `się` shows *some* degree of affixed rather than Wackernagelian behaviour, and Polish is a "northern" language in purely geographical terms. Any possibility of a spread by contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что я нашла.
 Все имевшиеся в исходной системе древнерусского языка у возвратного местоимения падежные формы были тождественны формам местоимения ты. Следовательно, они отличались от современных форм только в род.-вин. пад. (др.-русск. себе — современное себя) и в дат.-местн. над. (др.русск. соб-k — современное себе)."В дат. и вин. пад. у этого местои мения, как и у ты, были энклитические формы: си и **ся** Падежные формы возвратного местоимения широко отмечаются в памятни ках: род. пад.— оу себе (Новг. гр. 1305 г.), а межи себе оучинили (Двин. гр. XV в.) и (под влиянием дат.-местн. пад.) межю собе (Лавр, лет.), промеж собе (Новг. гр. 1471 г.); дат. пад.— коупи соб*Ь (Двин. гр. XV в.), мы соб-k боудемъ, а ты соб-k (там же), головоу си розби(х) дважды (там же); вин. пад.— ХОТА мстити себе (Лавр, лет.), возьмоутъ на сл. (там же); местн. пад.— по соб\ (Грам. 1447—1456 гг.), и рече в соб-k (Лавр, лет.) и т. д. Пути изменения этих форм или утраты их, так же как и причины таких изменений, у возвратного местоимения были теми же, что и у местоимения ты, и поэтому не требуют подробных комментариев: и здесь в род.-вин. пад. установилась форма себя вместо др.-русск. себе, а в дат.-местн. пад.— форма себе вместо др.-русск. соб-k; энклитические же формы были утрачены. Однако форма вин. пад. ся (а в говорах иногда дат, пад. си) не просто исчезла из языка, а превратилась в особую частицу, служащую для образования возвратных глаголов. В древнерусском языке форма СА, являясь ме стоимением, употреблялась в возвратном значении, не сливаясь с глаголом в одно целое: она могла выступать и после, и перед глаголом, а могла быть и отделена от глагола иными словами (ср. в Смоленской грамоте 1229 г.: что СА дкете по веремьнемь; в Лаврентьевской летописи: а га возъвращю СА похожю и еще). Превращаясь в возвратную частицу, ся теряло свою самостоятельность и полностью сливалось с глаголом, сначала семантически, а за тем фонетически и морфологически, образуя его возвратную форму. Этот процесс отражается в памятниках **с XV в.** (Иванов)

Другой источник.(Черных) Устранение подвижности частицы ся относится к позднему времени (XVI—XVlI вв.). Закрепление произошло сначала в области глаголов со значением страдательным и собственно-возвратным, а потом в (XVII в.) и в области остальных глаголов с частицей ся. В Уложении 1649 г. не имеется ни одного случая свободного употребления частицы ся.